# LINQ to Sql, cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

```
private decimal GetBankAccountCashierTotal()
{
    var company = _context.Company.FirstOrDefault();

    return _context.PersonBankAgencyAccount
           .Where(p => p.PersonID.Equals(company.PersonID))
           .Where(c => c.BankAgencyAccountBalance
                .Any(b => b.Reference <= DateTime.Now))
           .Select(x => x.BankAgencyAccountBalance
                .Where(d => d.Reference.Date <= DateTime.Now)
                .OrderByDescending(d => d.Reference)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .CurrentBalance)
           .sum();
}
```

This is my complete method, in the call of this method I get an exception

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code

and output

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler:Error: An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The good news are that the problem is not in your (absolutely valid) LINQ query.

The bad news are that currently (v.1.1.0) EF Core LINQ query translation/processing is still a total nightmare. After a lot of trial and error, getting either incorrect SQL (hence SQL exceptions) or different internal exceptions from EF Core infrastructure, the **only(!)** way I was able to get the desired result with single SQL and no exceptions is as follows (must be written **exactly** this way):

```
return _context.PersonBankAgencyAccount
       .Where(p => p.PersonID.Equals(company.PersonID))
       .SelectMany(p => _context.BankAgencyAccountBalance
           .Where(b => b.AccountId == p.Id && b.Reference.Date <= DateTime.Now)
           .OrderByDescending(b => b.Reference)
           .Take(1))
       .Sum(b => b.CurrentBalance);
```

Of course since using navigation property doesn't work, I guessed some names, you can replace them with yours if needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly but I still have a question, will Microsoft allow me to do this type of query in query that contains subqueries or this is a problem arising from the database in not accepting this type of query

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, it's a current EF Core limitation/bug/incorrect SQL translation. For instance EF6 has no problems translating such queries (and many others).

Comment: The problem with this code is that it is loading information into the database, I'll probably have to wait for Microsoft to optimize EFCore translations );

Comment: This is [fixed](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3792) in EF Core 2.0.0-preview1.

Comment: `SelectMany` was the solution in my case.